# Symfony2 Admin Login route config not found

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

I am adding admin login for Symfony2 Login Configuration. I got an error saying 'adminlogged' path not found. No matching route in your routing configuration!

[image]

Security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    MPW\TemplateBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1
    MPW\TemplateBundle\Entity\Admin:
        algorithm: sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
     users:
        entity: { class: TemplateBundle:User, property: email }
     admin:
        entity: { class: TemplateBundle:Admin, property: email }
     #my_custom_hwi_provider:
     #   id: my_user_provider


firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        provider: users
        form_login:
            login_path:  user_login
            check_path:  login_check
            default_target_path: dashboard
        logout:
            path: log_out

    admin_secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: ~
        provider: admin
        form_login:
            login_path:  admin_login
            check_path:  admin_check
            default_target_path: /admin_dashboard

access_control:
   - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   - { path: ^/admin-login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Routing.yml:

```
user_login:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: LandingPageBundle:Landing:login }

admin_login:
    pattern:  /admin-login
    defaults: { _controller: LandingPageBundle:Landing:adminLogin }

login_check:
    pattern:  /logged
admin_check:
    pattern:  /adminlogged
```

User Login is working fine but the admin login feature is having an issue

Comment: What are the differences between `Entity\User` and `Entity\Admin`? Have you tried to use only one class for both roles? I think it's easier to have only one entity for the users and set a `roles` column in order to differentiate regular users and administrators.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a controller for your `admin_check` route:

<kbd>routing.yml</kbd>

```
login_check:
    pattern:  /logged
admin_check:
    pattern:  /adminlogged
    defaults: { _controller: LandingPageBundle:Landing:adminLogin } # line added
```

There is no controller for the `login_check` route because it's managed by Symfony2:

> You will not need to implement a controller for the /login_check URL as the firewall will automatically catch and process any form submitted to this URL. However, you must have a route (as shown here) for this URL, as well as one for your logout path (see Logging Out).

Source: [official Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form).

Comment: With this solution, the URL changed to /adminlogged and landed back again in admin login page. I guess something more has to be done here.

Comment: Yes, you have to add a function in the Controller in order to check the password for the administrators. I'll update my answer later if I find a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to mimic the `login_check` route and its controller.